# TFS Build 2008 - Why is everything getting dumped in one folder?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When I build my solution, it dumps all the binaries into one folder. How can I cause it to split up the files by project like Visual Studio does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit your TFSBuild.proj file for the build, and add this to opne of the property groups:

```
<CustomizableOutDir>true</CustomizableOutDir>
```

This will automatically then cause the build to output the build output as per normal (like Visual Studio).